# PHP make a request check if client is available via ip

Tags: php, python, mysql, request, ip

I'm making a server which is controlled by php scripts, i have clients (androidphones) who calls these script to control the server. I'm saving the ip's the php receives to the DB.

now i'm looking for a way to check if these ip's are still reachable..

this is what i tried so far:

- Cron job -> i'm developing with usbwebserver so i cant use php from cmd
- make a ping request to the ip from the php script: if available it will return rather "fast" but if it fails i get the maximum excution error. this way of working get me the results i want but without the possibilty of threading this, this solution isnt going to perform in time as i wanted. is there a way this approach could work?
- something i'm considering:      -

  - make a request to de device through http, and do something with the result i get back, is this even possible (making a request from server to client)?
  - making a python script that gets the ip from db and makes the ping calls and stores the results back into the db.
  - making timestamps when a device connects and check timestamps from other devices, if max time was exceeded then update DB

any suggestions?

Comment: im pretty sure, 99.9% of enduser home routers are set by default not to respond to ICMP pings also the route would need tobe in place for the device to respond, also your client or android will not have a service running with an open port to respond to the ping. bit of a tricky one, pahaps your better of with a heartbeat from the client and use a timeout. if the client is requesting data then its online.

Comment: Even if you successfully ping an IP, that doesn't mean you're reaching the same device that made the original request. I would guess that most mobile devices get a new IP address every time they reconnect to the network, no?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have pinged to the android no problem... i will try the heartbeat approach. thx for replying. for the other replier: if they lose the connection the device still needs to go through the php which catches the new ip.. so the ip is up to date. btw i'm using this in a lan network

Answer (score 1):

I would do a ping to the client to see if it's still active.

Try using sockets to ping the client. Have a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php#101012

Answer (score 0):

This will not work, as you will always must have your client responding. I suggest using the client (eg. in html using javascript) to make a connection (ping) every minute from your script on the client to your server, and in your cronjobs letting a script run every x minutes to update the clients that didn't within x.

Comment: Alright, then i suggest everytime the script is executed, let it check/update. Alternative, you could use php, by making a seperate map and disable the maximum exectution time for a php script in there. In that case you could execute a neverending script; by using php sleep() you could set a delay.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no point in such checking.
You will always have these IPs UP.
Just because an android client seldom have a real IP but using Net via some router/proxy.

Web is one-way road.
To implement a heart-beat feature you have to make your android clients to ping server.